# Can I get reverse debugging functionality for Visual Studio 2013 Professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, gdb, reverse-debugging

I know that GDB comes with reverse debugging, but is there a way I can get this functionality in Visual Studio 2013 Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Visual Studio** (**2010, 2012, 2013 Ultimate** only) **does** have a feature that allows you to step backwards from a breakpoint or exception (Intellitrace), and the values in the *Locals* and *Autos* panes (as well as *DataTips* that appear on a hover over a statement) will the show the state at that (previous) point.  Unfortunately, Intellitrace is ***not*** available for 2013 Professional.  In addition, it has only limited support for F# and does ***not*** support C++ or JavaScript.

Right now, (since no 3rd party extensions exist that I’m aware of) your best option is looking at the call stack to examine the source code that executed prior to the breakpoint or exception.  BTW you *can* “drag” the debug point up and down in the debug gutter of the VS source window but this will ***only*** set the point of next execution (any previous state information is not displayed).

Since GDB does have this feature you *could* try something like [VisualGDB](http://visualgdb.com/) or [WinGDB](http://www.wingdb.com/), but I'm not sure how well reverse debugging is supported in either of these two or their stability once introduced into the most recent VS IDE.

Comment: More details on IntelliTrace can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx).